# Is it possible to disconnect a GUI program launched within vifm from vifm?

Tags: gnu-screen, job-control, vifm

One can launch GUI programs, for example, `gv` or `xpdf` from `vifm` in background in `vifm`'s command line:

```
 :!gv %f &
```

However, if `gv` is launched by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on a file like aPSfile.ps in `vifm`, it blocks the `vifm`. Is it possible to run it in the background as well when it is launched this way? The following setup in `vifmrc` does not work:

```
FILETYPE=PS=ps,eps,epsi=gv &
```

My current solution is to run `vifm` in GNU `screen`. `gv` launched by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will run in a new screen instead of blocking `vifm`. However, I'd like to save that screen as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [vifm documentation](http://vifm.sourceforge.net/docs.html) explicitly covers this requirement:

> **:filet[ype] pat1,pat2,... [{descr}]def_prog[ &],[{descr}]prog2[ &],...**
> Space followed by an ampersand as two last characters of a command means running of the command in the background.

I have

```
filetype *.pdf apvlv &
```

in my `.vifm/vifmrc` and it backgrounds any `.pdf` files I open, allowing me to close out of `vifm` and have `apvlv` still open.

Comment: seems my version of vifm, 0.4, is too old to have this build-in command. Thanks. I will update my vifm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer here because this question pops up for various searches for executing the application under the cursor in vifm. The original answer works for filetypes (as the op asked for).

However here's how to add a binding that will run an executable under the cursor (i.e. a gui application) in the background from vifm.

Add a key binding like this to your vifmrc file so that pressing `gx` will attempt to execute the entity under the cursor in the background:

```
nnoremap gx :!%d/%c &<cr>
```